# Can't add instance of class that implements an interface to a List of said interface in C#

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

For the following piece of code:

When I try to add to the list:

```
if (information != null) // not empty
{
    foreach (CharacterInformation info in information)
    {
        chButtons.Add(new GuiSelectCharacterButton(
            selectGui,
            new Rectangle(100, 100, 450, 100)
        ));
        chButtons[chButtons.Count - 1].ImageTexture = GUISprites.Instance().GetTexture(UITexture.RainbowDash);
        chButtons[chButtons.Count - 1].Texture = GUISprites.Instance().GetTexture(UITexture.CommonButtonNotPressed);
        chButtons[chButtons.Count - 1].PressedTexture = GUISprites.Instance().GetTexture(UITexture.CommonButtonPressed);
        chButtons[chButtons.Count - 1].ImageTextureWidth = 90;
        chButtons[chButtons.Count - 1].ImageTextureHeight = 90;
        chButtons[chButtons.Count - 1].ButtonPressed += LoginCharacterHandler;
        chButtons[chButtons.Count - 1].Font = GameFonts.Instance().GetSpriteFont(FontType.UI);
        chButtons[chButtons.Count - 1].Information = information[chButtons.Count - 1];
    }
}
// error at this line
buttoncontainer.ButtonList = chButtons;
```

Class declaration:

```
public class GuiSelectCharacterButton : GUIImageButton, IGameUserInterfaceImageButton
{
    public GuiSelectCharacterButton(GUI parent, Rectangle area)
        : base(parent, area)
    {

    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IGameUserInterfaceImageButton : IGameUserInterfaceComponent
{
    bool InsideContainer { get; set; }
    Rectangle InsideContainerArea { get; set; }
}
```

List of IGameUserInterfaceImageButton:

```
private List<IGameUserInterfaceImageButton> buttonList;

public List<IGameUserInterfaceImageButton> ButtonList
{
    get
    {
        return buttonList;
    }
    set
    {
        buttonList = value;
        scrollbarThumbTotalHeight = marginButtons;
        scrollbarThumbY = 0;
        int yhelper = 0;
        foreach (IGameUserInterfaceImageButton button in buttonList)
        {
            yhelper += marginButtons;
            button.InsideContainer = true;
            button.InsideContainerArea = new Rectangle(
                marginXbutton,
                yhelper,
                button.Area.Width,
                button.Area.Height
            );
            yhelper += marginButtons + button.Area.Height;
            scrollbarThumbTotalHeight += button.Area.Height + marginButtons * 2;
        }
        scrollbarThumbDrawHeight = 0;
        if (scrollbarThumbTotalHeight > Area.Height)
        {
            scrollbarThumbDrawHeight = (int)Math.Pow(AreaScrollbar.Height, 2) / scrollbarThumbTotalHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know where my mistake is. The base class (GUIImageButton) implements everything of said interface. I did this on other parts of my program but for any weird reason it doesn't work here.

Comment: What is type of chButtons from the first code block?

Comment: What's the type of `chButtons`? `List<GuiSelectCharacterButton>` ?

Comment: Which version of C# are you using..? This seems a covariance problem, and if I remember correctly the handling of that changed in C# 4.0 (or 3.0) - need to check.

Comment: chButtons = new List<GuiSelectCharacterButton>();

Comment: @MiMo C# only supports covariance on interfaces, not concrete classes like `List`, and then only when you are explicit about it in the interface definition, which `IList` is not. (Technically it also works  on delegates and has always worked on arrays, but that's not what we have here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast directly from `List<A>` to `List<IA>` event when `A` inherits from `IA`.

What you can do is make `chButtons` also of type `IGameUserInterfaceImageButton`.  Then cast each item to the interface, as you add them:

```
var chButtons = new List<IGameUserInterfaceImageButton>();
chButtons.Add(
    (IGameUserInterfaceImageButton)new GuiSelectCharacterButton(
        // etc ...
    )
);
// this is now valid
buttoncontainer.ButtonList = chButtons
```

Comment: The cast useless code gunk, because `Gui..Button` is implicitly convertible to `I..Button`.

Comment: Used a different approach anyways, the code was crap. Created a new instance of the Button and then added it to the list

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer:

If we have an interface and a class that implements it:

```
public interface IFoo { }
public class Foo : IFoo { }
```

This *does not* work:

```
var x = new List<Foo>();
x.Add(new Foo());
var y = new List<IFoo>();
y = x;
```

This *does* work:

```
var x = new List<IFoo>();
x.Add(new Foo());
var y = new List<IFoo>();
y = x;
```

### Explanation

Your problem is not in trying to add instances to your list; the `chButtons.Add()` method is working fine.

Your problem is when trying to assign `chButtons` to `buttoncontainer.ButtonList`. Those two identifiers do not have the same type. You've said what type `ButtonList` is, but you haven't said what `chButtons` is.

If, as I suspect, `chButtons` is a `List<GuiSelectCharacterButton>`, then what you're doing won't work. You cannot assign a `List<Foo>` to a `List<IFoo>` even if `Foo : IFoo`; this is called "covariance", and C# does not support it on concrete classes.

If you define `chButtons` to have the exact same type as `ButtonList`, e.g. a `List<IGameUserInterfaceImageButton>`, then your code should work fine.